# Unity3D 3.5 pro - Moving the camera vs setting draw distance

Tags: unity, camera

I move the camera mostly via right-click + WASD, sometimes with [shift] if I want it to move faster. Occasionally, instead of moving my camera, it alters the draw distance / FOV / some visual aspect of the editing scene that causes trees and other object to disappear when I scroll enough, and eventually even the terrain starts disappearing. It is not m "zooming out". My camera does not move, the width and height of the FOV stays the same (one might say the depth is being altered though). What key am I hitting to cause this to happen, and is it possible to disable it?

<sup>side note: "keybinds" is probably the most *spot-on* tag for this question but it doesn't exist (surprisingly) and I lack the rep to create it.</sup>

Comment: maybe you mean FOV(field of view) instead of draw distance.

Comment: What do you mean by "alters the draw distance or something"?  It's difficult to help without really knowing what's happening.

Comment: Well the problem is I don't know exactly what it's doing, least of all the name for it. Is there a list of default keybindings used by Unity? To start, which keybinds involving the mouse change the draw distance? FOV?

Comment: I'm not sure if anything's changed in 3.5 but look here for what's set by default: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-InputManager.html

Comment: It kind of sounds like you might be altering the far clip of the projection matrix. I don't know unity, but if there is a keybinding for that, it might be worth a loook.

Comment: How about adding a couple of screenshots of the Unity interface and your project before and after things go wrong? That might give people a better idea of what's happening. A Youtube/Vimeo/whatever video would be even better.

Comment: @Elideb For sure, it's just annoying to replicate of course, because I don't know how to deliberately do it. It'll come up one of these days though and I'll fraps it.

Comment: @stoicfury, this has been a problem with Unity for a while. To reset the camera far clip plane in the edtior, you basically have to focus on the gameobject you want it to target by double clicking on the object or in the scene editor.

Answer (score 1):

The camera type is preserved when you save your scene and will set itself the next time you open it. You have had your Scene window camera set to Isometric at some point in your scene and saved it. Restart your view layout by using the selection box top right of Unity3D or Shift+Left Click on the Axis widget box to switch between Isometric and Perspective.

[image: Perspective]

[image: Isometric]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your objects scale is to large, so when you're going backwards objects doesn't fit in your FOV. Try to rescale everything so that 1 game unit would be equal to about 1 meter.Let's say tree height should be about 4 units.